# Lambda usage is confusing me

Tags: c#, asp.net, lambda

So I am implementing a project from a book and I am somewhat confused as to WHY i need these lambdas.

```
public class Cart
{
    private List<CartLine> lineCollection = new List<CartLine>();
    public class CartLine
    {
        public Product Product { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
    public void RemoveLine(Product product)  
    {
        lineCollection
          .RemoveAll(p => p.Product.ProductID == product.ProductID);
    }
}
```

Why do I need `.RemoveAll(p=> p.Product.ProductID == product.ProductID)`?
Does it just have to do with `.RemoveAll` NEEDING a lambda expression?  I'm not sure why I can't use `this.Product.ProductID`, I realize Product is a list, is `p=> P.Product` doing some sort of iteration and comparing the values till it finds what it needs?

Product is defined in

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

I'm generally confused as to the purpose of Lambdas in these kinds of things.  Is there some equivelant to `p=>p.Product.ProductID == product.ProductID` 
I could see not using Lambdas so I could understand more what it is shorthand for??

I can't seem to wrap my head around this one, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RemoveAll` implementation has some sort of iterator which calls your anonymous function for each iteration. Like:

```
iterator {
    your_lambda_function(current_item);
}
```

And `p => p.Product.ProductID == product.ProductID` can be rewritten as:

```
delegate(CartLine p) { return p.Product.ProductID == product.ProductID; }
```

which could look a bit clearer for you

Comment: Ah that does make a lot of sense then.  So some of these implementations contain iterators and you are passing it a way to resolve each item.  
So I understand passing functions to resolve what to build the set from in an iterator, one question then please,
I am guessing not all these linq things contain iterators.  I see like in another class [This is in a Product] .OrderBy(p=> p.ProductID)
I'm mildly confused on that becaues it's not like it is using ProductID to resolve some set, it is somehow using it as a criterion? Does that function as just like a reference to ProductID?

Comment: @Jordan: nope, in `OrderBy` example you just pass the lambda that will be used to return the value the collection uses to sort by. You could pass `p => generate-random-value` and get the random ordering each time. So it is not a reference to `ProductID`, but just some value.

Answer (score 6):

They are a shorthand for a delegate. In your case, the same code without lambdas would look like this:

```
    public void RemoveLine( Product product )
    {
        var helper = new RemoveAllHelper();
        helper.product = product;

        lineCollection.RemoveAll( helper.TheMethod );
    }

    class RemoveAllHelper
    {
        public Product product;
        public bool TheMethod( CartLine p ) { return p.Product.ProductID == product.ProductID; }
    }
```

Because your lambda contains a variable that is defined outside of the lambda (called "bound" or "captured" variable), the compiler has to create a helper object with a field to put that variable into.

For lambdas without bound variables, a static method may be used:

```
    public void RemoveLine( Product product )
    {
        lineCollection.RemoveAll( TheMethod );
    }

    public static bool TheMethod( CartLine p ) { return p.Product.ProductID == 5; }
```

When the only bound variable is `this`, then an instance method on the same object may be utilized:

```
    public void RemoveLine( Product product )
    {
        lineCollection.RemoveAll( this.TheMethod );
    }

    public bool TheMethod( CartLine p ) { return p.Product.ProductID == this.targetProductID; }
```

Comment: Note that Lambda expression is converted to delegate if needed (as in this case), but it may also be Expression tree if context requires it - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Don't add unnecessary complexity right away. Let the OP learn one thing at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Download a trial version of ReSharper; it lets you convert from lambdas to delegates to named functions and such just by pressing alt-enter and choosing which one you want.  That is what helped me learn to understand what was what.

Answer (score 1):

Lambdas are not required. You could just as well replace them with the name of a method that implements the same signature.

Answer (score 1):

You can also remove them like regular.

```
public void RemoveLine(Product product) {
    for (var i = 0; i < lineCollection.Count;) {
        if (lineCollection[i].Product.ProductID == product.ProductID) {
            lineCollection.RemoveAt(i);
        } else { ++i; }
    }
}
```

I think the lambda is nicer though.  (in fact, looking at this code should demonstrate why using functors (be they lambdas or named functions) makes for much more understandable code).